# Zero stack segment in amd64 in long mode

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-64, memory-segmentation

This code stub was extracted from linux kernel 3.18.3, `arch/x86/boot/compressed/head_64.S`. There were added extra comments though.

All this code is executed in long mode (64 bits) with code segment selector: 0x10 and data segment selector: 0x18

```
xorl    %eax, %eax /* Setting up all data segments selectors to zero */
movl    %eax, %ds  /* Including stack segment */
movl    %eax, %es
movl    %eax, %ss
movl    %eax, %fs
movl    %eax, %gs

leaq    z_extract_offset(%rbp), %rbx

/* Set up the stack */
leaq    boot_stack_end(%rbx), %rsp

/* Zero EFLAGS */
pushq   $0 /* This instruction should fail since stack segment selector */
popfq      /* is zero (pointing to null descriptor) /*
```

According to what I know this code should fail to execute because %ss = 0x0 which points to null descriptor in the gdt, when the stack instruction pushq is executed.

Nevertheless this seems to work, so I assume I'm missing some information.
Why does this work?

Comment: Is long mode == IA-32e mode Intel speak? The Intel manual seems to say that just setting SS to 0 gives an exception: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33198311/895245

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segmentation is mostly disabled in 64-bit mode, with only attributes of CS and the base of FS and GS being used.