# Why have the first segment descriptor of the global descriptor table contain only zeroes?

Tags: assembly, x86

In many tutorials I've seen, the first a segment selector contains only zeros, followed by the code and data segments, e.g.:

```
lgdt gdt_descriptor
/* More code. */

gdt_start:
gdt_null:
    .long 0x0
    .long 0x0
/* More descriptors. */
gdt_end:
gdt_descriptor:
   .word gdt_end - gdt_start
   .long gdt_start
```

What is the purpose of this first `gdt_null` segment descriptor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intel manual 325384-053U part 3 section 3.4.2 Segment Selectors says that any attempt to access memory through the 0th descriptor by a segment register leads to an exception:

> The first entry of the GDT is not used by the processor. A segment selector that points to this entry of the GDT (that
>   is, a segment selector with an index of 0 and the TI flag set to 0) is used as a “null segment selector.” The processor
>   does not generate an exception when a segment register (other than the CS or SS registers) is loaded with a null
>   selector. It does, however, generate an exception when a segment register holding a null selector is used to access
>   memory. A null selector can be used to initialize unused segment registers. Loading the CS or SS register with a null
>   segment selector causes a general-protection exception (#GP) to be generated.

So this seems to imply that it is not possible to use it properly, and that therefore you can use it for whatever you want.

Zeroing it then is just the simplest thing to do, but any value could be used instead.